# Failed to execute 'update' on 'ApplicationCache': there is no application cache to update

Tags: javascript, caching

ApplicationCache won't cache anything
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.appcache">
<head>
<title>Zipcode Database</title>
```

File **cache.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
my.js
```

**htacces** file

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

When in console i run

```
applicationCache.update();
```

then error :
 **InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'update' on 'ApplicationCache': there is no application cache to update.
code: 11
message: "Failed to execute 'update' on 'ApplicationCache': there is no application cache to update."
name: "InvalidStateError"
stack: "Error: Failed to execute 'update' on 'ApplicationCache': there is no application cache to update.↵**

And `applicationCache.cache =0`

Comment: Did that fix it? Any update on my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cache.appcache` looks invalid, it should look like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#v0.0.1 change this to force update

CACHE:
./my.js
```

if it's still not working after this, can you provide me a full HTML so I can test it more?

Comment: To future downvoters / question seekers: Bruno is correct, perhaps the TS had his `my.js` linked wrong and with my answer it did linked correctly.

Answer (score 9):

The manifest is perfectly fine, the different sections are purely optional.

If the status is `0`, that simply means that the browser never successfully downloaded the manifest and all of it's contents. So if you want to manually run the `applicationCache.update()` method, make sure there is a cache at all and that it's not currently being updated, eg

`status == 1 || status > 3`

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/ for more information.

Comment: Why exclude status == 2 (applicationCache.CHECKING) ?

Comment: status == 2 is CHECKING, meaning that there might not be a cache, so you wouldn't want to swap it.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that error today in Chrome Browser. I have App Cache and Service Worker enabled in my app. So when you disable service worker it works as expected. But when you have both, Update cache event is triggered but applicationCache.swapCache(); throws that error.

so workaround is conditionally add that listener

```
if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
    function updateSite(event) {
       window.applicationCache.swapCache();

       if (confirm("New App Version Was Downloaded. Update now?")) {
           window.location.reload();
       }
    }

    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', updateSite, false);
}
```