# Why is there no application cache to update?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, application-cache

I am working through Chapter 23 of Javascript for Web Developers.  Why does running

```
applicationCache.update()
```

from Chrome's console

return

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'update' on 'ApplicationCache': there is no application cache to update.
```

??

My HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html manifest="offline.appcache">   
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic Quiz</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">   
    </head>   
    <body>
        <!-- Here is the question and its possible answers -->
        <div class="questionEntire">
            <h3 class="questionTitle">Question title goes here</h3>
            <form>
                <button type="submit">Next</button>
                <div class="choices">
                    <!-- <input type="radio" name="answer" value="0"><span>Choice 1</span><br> -->
                    <!-- <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1"><span>Choice 2</span><br> -->
                    <!-- <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2"><span>Choice 3</span><br> -->
                    <!-- <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3"><span>Choice 4</span><br> -->
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
        <!-- This is the div that should be shown at the end -->
        <div class="totalDiv hideThis">
            <h3 class="total">Your Score is</h3>
            <p>total</p>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="eventUtilities.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My offline.appcache file

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#Comment

CACHE: 
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js main.js
main.js 

NETWORK:
*
```

I am unable to see any files in Chrome's web dev tools under Resource->Application Cache.  When I run applicationCache.status, 0 is always returned.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaellatch/uxtawuwv/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427595/failed-to-execute-update-on-applicationcache-there-is-no-application-cache